# Python Pandas: pass column name as argument inte function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, df, with article numbers as columns (hundreds) and dates as index rows. df contains the number of sold items per product and day. This is a simplified example of it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'banana': [1, 8], 'apple': [3, 6]})
```

which outputs:

```
             banana   apple
2023-01-01   1        3
2023-01-02   8        6
```

I have a dictionary with prices:

```
price_dict = {'banana': 10, 'apple': 100}
```

I'm trying to multiply the number of sold fruits with the price of that fruit for every given day by a function like this:

```
def get_sales(quantity, fruit):
    return price_dict[fruit] * quantity
```

and then I want to create a new DataFrame with the sales by calling that function, like this:

```
df_sales = df.apply(lambda x: get_sales(x, x.column)
```

expecting following outcome:

```
             banana   apple
2023-01-01   10       300
2023-01-02   80       600
```

However, I can't figure out how I can pass the column name into the function. How can I use the name of the column in a dictionary, like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pass columns names here use `x.name`:

```
df_sales = df.apply(lambda x: get_sales(x, x.name))
```

If need multiple by dictionary with keys by columns names simplier is:

```
df_sales = df.mul(price_dict)
#df_sales = df * price_dict
print (df_sales)
   banana  apple
0      10    300
1      80    600
```